# How to define parameters/constants in Apache .htaccess files

Tags: apache-http-server, environment-variables, redirection, htaccess

I don’t have access to the Apache server configuration files and can only influence the configuration through `.htaccess` files.
Unfortunately, this rather limits some things one might want to do.
For example, the easiest way to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS would be:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} != 'on'">
    Redirect permanent / https://www.my-domain.com/
</If>
```

However, this forces me to hard-code the domain name, so I can’t reuse this `.htaccess` file easily.
In my case, the same site can be accessed from several different domains (with only one underlying filesystem), so this is not an option for me at all.
I can’t solve this by redirecting to `https://%{SERVER_NAME}/` since the `Redirect` statement doesn’t support this kind of variable substitution ([except in `<Location>` or `<LocationMatch>` sections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), but of course, [these are not available to `.htaccess` files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location)).

So already, if I want to have a general/reusable `.htaccess` configuration, I’m forced to use `mod_rewrite` instead of `Redirect` so I can use server variable substitution.
The corresponding solution is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
```

which is already significantly more complex, not to mention possible interactions with other `mod_rewrite` rules I might want to set up – preferably, I would like to keep use of `mod_rewrite` to a minimum due to its complexities.

---

Another example, for which I haven’t found a workaround at all, is `mod_substitute`, which doesn’t support `%{variable}` expansion at all.
If my site is in a specific subdirectory (`sub_dir`) on the server and I want to post-process all links on HTML pages in that directory, I can do

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute s~/sub_dir/[^\s]+/~/sub_dir/something_else/~
```

so here, I have to hard-code the directory `sub_dir`, which I would have to replace for every other subdirectory I might want to perform the same substitution in (no, I don’t have access to the root URL `/`).
If this were a rewrite rule, I could just define an environment variable `%{env:site_dir}` like so:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=site_dir:/sub_dir]
```

but this environment variable is of no use to me because `mod_substitute` doesn’t interpret these.

---

So, is there any way to avoid hard-coding and duplicating domains and subdirectories like this in modules like `mod_alias` or `mod_substitute`, which don’t have the same mechanisms as `mod_rewrite`?
For example, by somehow getting access to environment variables like `%{env:variable}` in these modules?

Comment: My use case is that I want to upload my .htaccess file to several websites or directories. Currently, I have to create a separate .htaccess file for each one, with custom ErrorDocument and other directives. This is error-prone unless I use a macro expander, but my text editor won't run external programs. Expression substitution is a pretty fundamental requirement, yet Apache's solutions are arcane, with no improvement at all over many years. Just my opinion.

Comment: Using expressions or rewrite rules in Apache is very difficult because there is no way to debug .htaccess files. Not even a "print" statement that would output to the browser or to a file. If you use a complex regular expression or rewrite rule there could be a future bug even though it seems to work in a particular case.